# Priority for a web request in Java web applications

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to find out a way to associate an priority  with a web request.Essentially, I want my web container (Tomcat e.g.) to always process web requests with a higher priority first.

E.g. say it is currently processing many lower priority web requests and has reached its limits of concurrent web requests. If a higher priority web request comes in, it will pause one of the lower web requests and work on the higher priority request.

The purpose of this is that some of the web requests are for batch processing, which will ultimately be translated into a set of lower priority web requests, and is expected to take longer, whereas some web requests are for people interacting with the website and shouldn't be delayed, thus higher priority.

This doesn't necessarily have to be a feature of the web container. If there's another way to do this (Any sort of task scheduler, although I can't find anything that respects a tasks priority), it would fit the purpose of this question.

Comment: Could you create a thread pool for the low priority requests and, as they come in, send them to the thread pool.  If you need to respond eventually you could always make the low priority requests asynchronous and when your thread pool task is finished it could fire off the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Servlet 3.0 async servlets, this will let you process each request asynchronously in a separate thread (with queuing possible if needed), rather than thread that accepted the request. Assign each thread the requisite priority (Thread.setPriority) with the batch threads at Thread.MIN_PRIORITY and the interactive threads at Thread.NORM_PRIORITY. Not exactly the pausing behavior you describe, but should be close enough.
For an example of async servlets, see https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/how-to-use-asynchronous-servlets-to-improve-performance

Comment: This only makes the spawned thread of a lower priority, but if that thread called external libraries that spawned additional threads, or if it called another system (like a database), the balancing wouldn't work anymore as intended (e.g. higher priority requests have same privilege for database requests as lower priority requests).

Comment: Yes, it is something one has to think about, and could be solved (for example with 2 replicated databases), in the case that both the lower priority and higher priority threads need to access the same database. However, that was not the question. For all I know, the lower priority thread is mining bitcoins